# Delete record from table ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY

Tags: flowable

I have lot of records in table ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY.
I want to keep only the last 15 days. I don't want to use the config.setEnableHistoryCleaning(true) and I am trying to do it manually.

I am trying to figure out which rows to delete from ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY table.
For rows that BYTEARRAY_ID_ I can do a join with one of the history tables (ACT_HI_DETAIL & ACT_HI_VARINST) and figure out the date the row is created.
What I noticed is that there are quite a few rows which BYTEARRAY_ID_ are not present in (ACT_HI_DETAIL & ACT_HI_VARINST) and DEPLOYMENT_ID_ is null
I am not sure whether to delete these rows or not and if I want to delete it, how to delete them. Most of the records in this table are of this type in my database.

Answer (score 1):

The `BYTEARRAY_ID_` is only set in case the data was too large for the other available fields. Assuming you are talking about a variable and the variable is a string, it will be stored in `text_` and `text2_`. In case the content doesn't fit in there, the byte array table is used.

A special case for the variables is when they are not plain text and a java object, in this case there is a byte array entry created. Normally, those get big quickly. That's why it is not recommended to store any Java objects in non transient variables. Rather than doing this, use either the JSON variable type or a custom variable type would be recommended. So in the best case, you don't have a (not that) fast growing byte array table when you stick to those principles.

You should certainly not delete all rows from the byte array table. Analyze if most of the rows are for example connected to a variable and delete those which you do not need.

Also, you might want to consider to change the history level that those variables are not getting persisted in the first place.